# Type (in)equalities in the presence of data families

Tags: haskell, dependent-type, type-families

I've got a type family which determines whether something is at the head of a type-level list.

```
type family AtHead x xs where
    AtHead x (x ': xs) = True
    AtHead y (x ': xs) = False
```

I want to construct the singleton representative of this result. This works fine for lists of simple types.

```
data Booly b where
    Truey :: Booly True
    Falsey :: Booly False

test1 :: Booly (AtHead Char [Char, Int])
test1 = Truey
test2 :: Booly (AtHead Int [Char, Int])
test2 = Falsey
```

But what I *really* want to do is construct this value for a list of members of an indexed `data family`. (In practice, I'm trying to project elements out of a heterogeneous list of `ID`s based on their type.)

```
data family ID a

data User = User
newtype instance ID User = UserId Int
```

This works when the `ID` we're looking for is at the head of the list.

```
test3 :: Booly (AtHead (ID User) [ID User, Char])
test3 = Truey
```

But it fails otherwise.

```
test4 :: Booly (AtHead (ID User) [Int, ID User])
test4 = Falsey

    Couldn't match type ‘AtHead (ID User) '[Int, ID User]’
                  with ‘'False’
    Expected type: Booly (AtHead (ID User) '[Int, ID User])
      Actual type: Booly 'False
    In the expression: Falsey
    In an equation for ‘test4’: test4 = Falsey
```

`AtHead (ID User) '[Int, ID User]` doesn't unify with `'False`. It looks like GHC is reluctant to make the judgment that `ID User` and `Int` are unequal, even though `ID` is an injective `data family` (and is therefore in principle equal only to (things that reduce to) `ID User`).

My intuition for what the constraint solver will and won't accept is rather weak: I feel like this ought to compile. Can anyone explain why my code doesn't type-check? Does there exist a way to cajole GHC into accepting it, perhaps by proving a theorem?

Comment: I know GHC isn't too good with injective data families.  Making a wrapper sometimes works, e.g. `newtype ID' a = ID' (ID a)`.

Comment: Seems to me like this might be a GHC bug. Those types ought to be "surely apart" (GHC technical term).

Comment: [Reported it](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10910).

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen Thanks for reporting it, I've cc-ed myself on the issue. @luqui The `newtype` thing does work but it's not very nice :(

Comment: (Just a terminology note. The property that tells you that `ID User` and `Int` are unequal is generativity, not injectivity. Data families are automatically both generative and injective, but an injective type family `ID'` could still satisfy `ID' User = Int`.)

Comment: And it looks like there was [an older ticket](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10713) that my googling attempts had missed. So this is already fixed in GHC HEAD!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this was a [known GHC bug](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/10713). The fix is already in GHC head, and should be in the next upcoming releases (GHC 8.0.1 and maybe 7.10.3).

Other than that, @luqui's suggestion of a newtype wrapper seems the simplest option.